# Read pickle.zip file in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to read multiple pickle.zip files.
I used :

```
 pd.read_pickle(r"C:\Users\Pix\Documents\X\Z\Y-03.pickle.zip" , compression="infer")
```

First of all it is taking huge time due to size and it ultimately fails. How to catch error?

Comment: could you please share your error.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'blocks'

Comment: Any other efficient way to read these kind of files. We do not have chunk size option in read_pickle.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pickle

objects = []
with (open("FILE", "rb")) as openfile:
    try:
        objects.append(pickle.load(openfile))
    except EOFError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: objects.append(pickle.load(openfile))
_pickle.UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered,
but no persistent_load function was specified.